# What is the expected speed of Magento 1.9 SOAP API v2 when listing all products?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

We have a Magento 1.9 site and a remote script that retrieves a listing of all products in the system via Magento's v2 SOAP API. This is working at approximately 2,500 products per minute. For a catalog of 10,000 products it takes around 4 minutes to retrieve the full listing.

The code we are using to list the products is:

```
$products = $proxy->catalogProductList(array("sessionId" => $sessionId, "filters" => $filters));
```

Is this performance normal or slower than expected?